# Java will not compile properly from the command line "cannot find my source files"

Tags: java, command-line, javac

I am trying to compile my source code from the Windows 7 command prompt. I have added the directory in which my `*.java` file is located to the classpath. Yet, I still get this error:

```
C:\Users\Alex>javac HelloThere.java
javac: file not found: HelloThere.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
```

I'm very confused as to why this happens because if I navigate to the folder where this file is located, it will compile. However, this is not a satisfactory solution since I intend on compiling JUnit tests directly from the command line as well.

Other solutions I have attempted:

```
C:\Users\Alex>javac -classpath "C:\Users\Alex\AndroidProject\UnitTest\src" HelloThere.java
javac: file not found: HelloThere.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
```

I do not think this has ANYTHING to do with typos.

Why can't I compile my project like this?

Comment: You have a space in your file and/or class name?  Remove it and try again.

Comment: Why on Earth, since no one else has asked, aren't you using an IDE such as **Eclipse**?

Comment: If a "Hello There" program is anything like a "Hello World" program, he may just be starting out :)  But you make a good point, next step, explore IDE's.

Answer (score 1):

The CLASSPATH variable is not used by javac to find where your source code lives. Use the [`-sourcepath` arg to javac](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/javac.html#options) instead.

Save yourself a lot of time and manual typing and use a build tool like [Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) or [Maven](http://maven.apache.org).

Comment: Or just save yourself a lot of time AND trouble by shortening that list down to Ant. :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to use classpath, that tells the compiler where to find externally referenced .class files used by your file.  You want to use -sourcepath which tells javac where your .java files may be hiding.